# Cannot write data into excel from access while workbook is open

Tags: ms-access, vba

When i try to write table contents from access to excel using vba code while workbook is already open, i don't see any updated data. Is there any reason for that.

Comment: Hard to say without more detail, but the most likely explanation is the file is locked while open.  That's pretty much what you would expect to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Excel locks the file for editing while it's open.

Comment: Can we be able to unlock it through code to write the contents?

Comment: Not as far as I know.  Excel is very strict about how it deals with open files.  As an example, you cannot open 2 files that have the same name, even if they are in different locations.  I think your only recourse is to have the file closed and editable while you're running your script on it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an intermediary workbook. Have access write to a separate closed workbook then reference that workbook in your open workbook... Not an elegant solution, but it should work.